# Connectedness of the punctured $n$-space

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering how is possible to show a notorius fact, i.e. that $\mathbb R^n - \{0\}$ is connected for $n > 1$ using only the following machinery:

> **Definition.** A topological space $S$ is *connected* iff the only sets which are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $S$.
>
> **Theorem 1.** A topological space is connected iff is not the union of two nonempty disjoint open sets.
>
> **Theorem 2.** Let $S$ be a topological space, and let $T_0$ and $\{ T_w\}_{w \in W}$ be connected subset of $S$. Assume $T_0 \cap T_w \neq \emptyset$ for each $w \in W$. Then $T_0 \cup ( \cup_{w\in W} T_w )$ is connected.

Suppose we know (as a matter of fact, unproved) that $\mathbb R$, intervals in $\mathbb R$, balls and cubes in $\mathbb R^n$ are connected. Then Theorem 2 easily implies that $\mathbb R^n$ is connected. Moreover, we note that a subset of a topological space is connected if it is connected in the relative topology. We can use stuff about relative topologies but we can't use the well-established theorem (nor its proof!) that if $X,Y$ are connected, then $X \times Y$ is connected and, furthermore, if $A$ is a proper subset of $X$ and $B$ a proper subset of $Y$, then $X \times Y - (A \times B)$ is connected. Suppose we haven't introduced continuous functions yet. Of course, we don't know about stronger forms of connectedness. (So most of the answers on this site are not valid in this setting!)

Since this exercise is proposed immediately after Theorem 2, first of all I've tried to take suitable $T_0$ and $T_w$. Since $\{0\}$ is ruled out, I've attempted something like $T_0 = B_1(0) - \{0\}$ (the punctured open ball) and $T_w$ half lines of the type $(0, \infty)$, indexed by some angles twisting on coordinate planes. Each $T_w$ intersects $T_0$, each is connected in the relative topology but showing that $T_0$ is connected too (to apply Theorem 2) seems quite the same thing as the original problem.

Then I've tried to argue by contraddiction, exploiting connectedness of $\mathbb R^n$, but I haven't reached a conclusion. Suppose $S:= R^n - \{0\}$ is not connected, the there exist $A,B$ in $S$ nonempty disjoint open sets such that $S = A \cup B$. Since $\mathbb R^n = ( \mathbb R^n - \{0\} )\cup \{0\}$, then $\mathbb R^n = A \cup B \cup \{0\}$. $A$ is open in $S$, so it is open in $\mathbb R^n$, being $S$ itself open in $\mathbb R^n$. Hence, $B \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$ and Theorem 1 doesn't apply.

As explained, I believe that the key is a smart choice of $T_0$ and $T_w$ but I can't see which one fits "well" (in a sense of minimality of further work).

Comment: Are you allowed to use that a line segment in $\mathbb R^n$ (with subspace topology) is homeomorphic to a line segment in $\mathbb R$? -  Or that $\{\,x\in\mathbb R^n\mid x_0=1\,\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen We don't have the notion of "homeomorphic" at this point; by the way, I think it could be allowed whether it doesn't introduce "tricks of too high level"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ia assume you can use that any straight line $\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is connected.

Let $T_0$ be any straight line not passing through $0$. 
Let $\{T_w\}_{w\in W}$ be the set of straight lines in $\mathbb R^n$ with $T_w\cap T_0\ne\emptyset$ and $0\notin T_w$.
Then by theorem 2 the set $A=T_0\cup\bigcup_{w\in W} T_w$ is connected. Show that $A=\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$. In fact let $x\in\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$ be given. If $x\in T_0$ we are done. Otherwise pick two distnct points $a,b\in T_0$. Then at least one of the two lines $ax$, $bx$ does not pass through $0$ and hence is a $T_w$.